# How to copy the username from spring security into a variable on JSP

Tags: jsp, spring-security, jstl

I need to copy the username of current user into a variable to be able to compare it with another variable.

I retrieve the username using

```
<sec:authentication property="name"/>
```

Now need to copy it into a variable to be tested in following if condition

```
<c:if test="${(name eq myuser.username)}">
     .........
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it I should use the following

```
  <sec:authentication var="currentUsername" property="name"/>
```